# Laravel 8 Error: Attempt to assign property "id_gerai" on null

Tags: php, html, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I building a page to insert rows into database tables using a HTML form. I created my view, model, controller, and route already and it return this error when i try to submit the form:

```
Attempt to assign property "id_gerai" on null
```

Here are the rest of the code

**resources\views\dashboard\manajemen_donasi.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.dashboard')

@section('title')
<title>KitaKenyang - Dashboard Admin</title>
@endsection

@section('nav_link')
<li class="nav-item active">
<a class="nav-link" href="/manajemen donasi">
  <i class="fas fa-fw fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
    <span>Manajemen Donasi</span></a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" href="/manajemen penyimpanan">
    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
    <span>Manajemen Penyimpanan</span></a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" href="/manajemen penyaluran">
    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
    <span>Manajemen Penyaluran</span></a>
</li>
@endsection

@section('username')
Admin
@endsection

@section('content')
<!-- Page Heading -->
<div class="d-sm-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-4">
                        <h1 class="h3 mb-0 text-gray-800 text-center">Dashboard Manajemen Donasi</h1>
                    </div>


                    <div class="container-fluid">
    
                        <!-- DataTales Example -->
                        <div class="card shadow mb-4">
                            <div class="card-header py-3">
                                <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-success">Input Donasi</h6>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                            <form action="#" method="post" class="probootstrap-form">
                            @csrf <!-- {{ csrf_field() }} -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="id_user">ID Donatur</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_user" name="id_user">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="tanggal">Tanggal Donasi</label>
                                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="tanggal" name="tanggal">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="id_kategori_barang">Kategori</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_kategori_barang" name="id_kategori_barang">  
                                <i>* dry staple: 1 | dehydrated food: 2 | canned food: 3 | frozen food: 4</i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="id_kuantitas">Kuantitas</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="kuantitas" name="kuantitas">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="id_nama_barang">Nama barang</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nama_barang" name="nama_barang">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="id_gerai">ID Gerai</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_gerai" name="id_gerai">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" id="submit" name="submit" value="Input">
                            </div>
                            </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
    
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
@endsection
```

**routes\web.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Models\Donasi;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');

Route::get('/beranda', 'PagesController@index');

Route::get('/tentang kami', 'PagesController@about');

Route::get('/berita', 'PagesController@news');

Route::get('/program', 'PagesController@program');

Route::get('/gerai donasi', 'PagesController@gerai');

Route::get('/login', 'PagesController@login');

Route::get('/register', 'PagesController@register');

Route::get('/kinerja organisasi', 'DashboardController@laporan_org');

Route::get('/donasi user', 'DashboardController@laporan_user');

Route::get('/profil user', 'DashboardController@profil_user');

Route::get('/manajemen donasi', 'DashboardController@manajemen_donasi');

Route::post('manajemen donasi', 'DashboardController@input_donasi');

Route::get('/manajemen penyimpanan', 'DashboardController@manajemen_penyimpanan');

Route::get('/manajemen penyaluran', 'DashboardController@manajemen_penyaluran');
```

**App\Models\Donasi.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Donasi extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'donasi';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = [
        'id_user',
        'id_kategori_barang',
        'id_gerai',
        'nama_barang',
        'kuantitas',
        'tanggal',
    ];
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

**app\Http\Controllers\DashboardController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Program;
use App\Models\DonasiDalamPenyimpanan;
use App\Models\TotalDonasi;
use App\Models\TotalDonatur;
use App\Models\Donasi;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function laporan_org()
    {
        $totaldonatur = TotalDonatur::all();
        $totaldonasi = TotalDonasi::all();
        $program = Program::all();
        return view('dashboard.laporan_org', compact('program', 'totaldonasi', 'totaldonatur'));
    }
    public function laporan_user()
    {
        return view('dashboard.laporan_user');
    }
    public function profil_user()
    {
        return view('dashboard.profil_user');
    }
    public function manajemen_donasi()
    {
        return view('dashboard.manajemen_donasi');
    }
    public function manajemen_penyimpanan()
    {
        $penyimpanan = DonasiDalamPenyimpanan::all();
        return view('dashboard.manajemen_penyimpanan', compact('penyimpanan'));
    }
    public function manajemen_penyaluran()
    {
        $program = Program::all();
        return view('dashboard.manajemen_penyaluran', compact('program'));
    }
    public function input_donasi(Request $request)
    {
        $donasi = new Donasi;
        $donasi->id_user = $request->input('id_user');
        $donasi->tanggal = $request->input('tanggal');
        $donasi->id_kategori_barang = $request->input('id_kategori_barang');
        $donasi->kuantitas = $request->input('kuantitas');
        $donasi->nama_barang = $request->input('nama_barang');
        $donasiModel->id_gerai = $request->input('id_gerai');
        $donasi->save();    

    }
}
```

Comment: It needs to have a value which is not null to the variable named `id_gerai`. Since you have put that variable to the model `$fillable` property. But you are trying to save data with null value of this variable. That's why it is throwing error.

Comment: the `$donasiModel->id_gerai` should be the source of the issue. I dont see `$donasiModel` declared anywhere in your code!

Comment: Yeah, it's just a typo as it turned out haha the $donasiModel->id_gerai should be $donasi->id_gerai. Thank you all